# Laravel mix splint chunks vendors

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

Am using laravel mix and have configured webpack split chunks as follows

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.vuetify('vuetify-loader');

 mix.webpackConfig({
   optimization :  {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
        minSize: 200000,
        maxSize: 244000,
    }
  }
 });
```

The above works but the vendor files are not created in the javascript and css directory. The manifest produced has the following.

```
{
 "/js/app~d0ae3f07.js": "/js/app~d0ae3f07.js",
 "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css",
 "/vendors~/js/app~2a42e354.js": "/vendors~/js/app~2a42e354.js",
 "/vendors~/js/app~30964246.js": "/vendors~/js/app~30964246.js",
 "/vendors~/js/app~fdc6512a.js": "/vendors~/js/app~fdc6512a.js"
```

}

How can i make it to extract the vendor files inside js/vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be extract i had not called `mix.extract()`